# Interagindo com o sistema linux

Tags: javascript, html, html5, angularjs

Exite alguma função ou maneira de se fazer com que o javascript/angularjs se comunique com o linux?

Por exemplo:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>{{kapp}}</h2>
        <div class="busca" id="div1">
            <input class="form-control"type="text" placeholder="Digite o nome completo" ng-model="search"/>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-info" id="bot" ng-click="buscar(search)" onclick="fecha();">
                Search  
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        angular.module('myApp', []);
        angular.module('myApp', []).controller("customersCtrl",function ($scope, $http)
        {   
            $scope.kapp = "Buscado";
            $scope.buscar = function (name)
            {
                $scope.search = name;
            }
    </script>
</html>
```

Bem, teria alguma maneira de quando 'name' receber um nome e esse nome ser passado para uma variavel de um arquivo Shellscript,python ou C ?

Comment: Não sem uma linguagem server-side, por exemplo [`php`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shell-exec.php)...

Comment: E usando o php, como faria isso?

Comment: Uma linguagem server-side (Ruby ou PHP, por exemplo) + REST Services.

Comment: @Matheus usando o php eu já respondi como sugestão de resposta.

Comment: Fazendo algo semelhante à resposta do @Sneeps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funciona assim @Matheus, você precisa de uma linguagem que esteja do lado do servidor, então se esse seu javascript, angularjs, html e html5 estiver no lado do cliente ( e muito provável que esteja ) não da p/ fazer o seu servidor executar comando nenhum, então no caso do php seria assim:

```
<?php 
exec(' teste="ola mundo"'); 
exec('echo teste > arquivo.txt '); 
?>
```

Então uma solução seria fazer um ajax no seu javascript para o php e fazer por lá, isso seria uma solução.

Claro que isso pode ser feito na linguam javascript mesmo, mas, porém, entretando, todavia, você vai precisar usar o javascript do lado do server, exemplo para fazer isso é o **nodeJs**, segue um link para fazer a mágica do comando unix direto do javascript ( com o nodeJs )

> https://nodejs.org/
>
> http://www.dzone.com/snippets/execute-unix-command-nodejs